# Scaling large images in browser causes frame-rate drop

Tags: javascript, browser

We have a zoomable canvas that contains images that users upload. Zooming is done using transform in CSS.

When zooming in, the page will often hang for a second, seemingly while it loads the image.

This is easiest to see through a screen recording:
https://www.loom.com/share/7d007e92fd8445889a47f2e28a2165a3

Note this image is 2880 × 16564 pixels. But what's actually going on here? Why is it slowing down when scaling up?

Note, we've tried adding `will-change: transform;` to the layer that will change, however this does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In the most cases you should never zoom a canvas. Draw your image zoomed inside the canvas.